# Elementtree, check if element has certain parent?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am parsing an xml file: http://pastebin.com/fw151jQN
I wish to read it in copy a lot of it and write it to a new file, some of it modified, a lot of it unmodified, and a lot of it ignored. As an initial pass I want to find certain xml, and write it to a new file unchanged.

Here is the section of the xml that is of interest at first:

```
<COMMAND name="shutdown"
        help="Shutdown the selected interface">
        <CONFIG priority="0x7F01" />
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 0
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>

    <COMMAND name="no shutdown"
        help="Enable the selected interface">
        <CONFIG operation="unset" pattern="shutdown"/>
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 1
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>
```

My code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('interface_range_test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
namespaces = {'command': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND','config': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG'}

all_links = tree.findall('.//')

for i in all_links: 
    if namespaces['command'] in i.tag:
        if i.attrib['name'] == "shutdown":
            print i.attrib       
    if namespaces['config'] in i.tag: 
        print i.attrib
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'shutdown', 'help': 'Shutdown the selected interface'}
{'priority': '0x7F01'}
{'pattern': 'shutdown', 'operation': 'unset'}
```

This reads in the file and I can find the shutdown information, now I want to find the `CONFIG` information, and then the `action` information and it's text, but when I search there is `CONFIG` information for both `shutdown` and `no shutdown`. This case will occur in a lot of the xml, a lot of it has the same format.

Shutdown:
    {'priority': '0x7F01'}
no shutdown:
    {'pattern': 'shutdown', 'operation': 'unset'}

How can I specify which to look at, can I check the parent of this information? Or can I check the children of the super element above it (`http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND`)?

Comment: have you considered xslt for this? after all it's designed to transform xml from one form to another...

Comment: @mata I'm afraid the code must go into a python script, my only option.

Comment: Do you have to use `findall('.//')`? Could you just iterate over the nodes on one level?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I dont have to, I just didnt know how to do what you are suggesting, I tried for ages and gave up for this method of searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search all COMMANDS as node（element), and getting CONFIG info from there, e.g.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('interface_range_test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for command in root.iter("{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND"):
    subs = list(command.iter('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG'))
    if len(subs） > 0: #we found CONFIG
        print command.tag, command.attrib, subs[0].tag, subs[0].attrib
```

And you will get:

```
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND {'name': 'shutdown', 'help': 'Shutdown the selected interface'} {http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG {'priority': '0x7F01'}
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND {'name': 'no shutdown', 'help': 'Enable the selected interface'} {http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG {'pattern': 'shutdown', 'operation': 'unset'}
```

BTW, if you need to handling big xml files, I would recommend to use [lxml](http://lxml.de), which also has [ElementTree compatible interface](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) but much faster than python's standard xml lib.

Comment: Thanks that's great! Then if I wanted the action tag and it's text I would have to do a search for action  on subs? Or I could use getchildren? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Paul, yes you can use command.getchildren() or list(command) to get all children of that element, check http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren to see other supported methods